# OpenVPN and Windows routing table

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

So I'm a student and I need to connect to my university VPN very often in order to use Matlab, AutoCAD, etc. I'm using their OpenVPN network instead of Windows PPTP, cause I have more control.
This VPN network is forcing to route all traffic through their server and I don't like it so I managed to disable this with adding **route-nopull** to client config. At this point programs can't connect to university license server, so I checked how routing tables looks after connecting to VPN (see pic). Now I know that the VPN server is giving IPs from this network **2xx.xx.26.0/30** so every computer is in different subnet. As you can see on the picture, that IP server gave me is **2xx.xx.26.105**, so the only option is the gateway is **2xx.xx.26.106**. License server IP in the network is **2xx.xx.28.34** and ID of interface I'm using is **29** so I added route rule with following command: `route add 2xx.xx.28.34 2xx.xx.26.106 if 29` (the result is marked red on picture). Now I can connect to license server, but everytime I reconnect to VPN, it can throw me to different subnet, gateway changes and I need to add another static route. Can I do something to avoid this? It is possible?
[MY ROUTING TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrDkl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a "--route-up" script!

You can then use the environment variable "route_vpn_gateway" in that script to route certain networks via the VPN gateway:

```
#!/bin/sh
route del all default
route add 2xx.xx.28.34 $route_vpn_gateway if $dev
# do this for ebery net that needs to be routed via the VPN
```

Comment: It's not working for me on Windows clients. With OpenVPN GUI I can't run the script even when I create file [config_name]_up.bat. I managed to run "--route-up" script when launching connection to server from command line, it works when I put static command, for example "route add 123.123.123.123 321.321.321.321 if 4" but environment variables provided on wiki don't work. When I try to read %dev% variable with echo, it just returns me "%dev%". I will try to figure how to get these variables working on Windows. Anyway thanks for pointing me to the right direction